# Running PHP in apache

Tags: php

Im a newbie to PHP and trying to run this code in apache webserver but for some reason its not running.

The file is saved under htdocs info.php. WHen I run there is no action at all..Infacts it opens the download window.

ANy help is appreciated

php code:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    echo date("F j, Y, g:i:s a");
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like Apache is not configured to properly parse PHP files.

Comment: nickb is right. What OS are you using?

Comment: For windows, http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php or use [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or good tutarial for linux and windows: http://www.blazonry.com/scripting/install_apache.php

Comment: check whether apache is running or not

Comment: For instance, in Ubuntu you need to run the following command to install the PHP parser:

    sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Comment: im running in windows..how do I configure in apache?

Comment: I tried to configure the php but now I get this error-cannot load  php5apache2.dll onto server..This file is not located under my php folder..where do Get it

Comment: Does your ISP block Google? I think you try to install a old version of apache or PHP because every forum post I found is dated 2006 - 2008.. Download a old PHP version (archive), then it should be in the extension or root dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what steps you took to install the web server, but did you install PHP and configured Apache to use it?

If the configuration isn't the main priority and programming in PHP is, then just download WAMP. This is a Apache webserver with PHP, PHPmyAdmin and MySQL already configured and ready to go.

Download at: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Although i rarely recommend using "all-in-one" XAMP packages I do make an exception when it comes to beginners.

In this case it would be much easier to simply download and use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) instead of nitpicking about what might be misconfigured on the existing web server.

Comment: And why do you not recommend "all-in-one" packages?

Comment: They are often too specifically configured and targeted toward beginners which is why sooner or later people willing to switch from simple experimenting to some serious development will face a problem. On the other hand "all in one" packages are way less painful for absolute beginners and usually provide enough pre-configured functionality to satisfy all of their needs.

Comment: I never had any problems with the default configuration of a complete package before. It are the same configuration files that you would end up when installing it all on your own. When I need some extra configuration, then I just edit the config files until they are what I want them to be. So why go through all the time and pain to install them separately? Can you give any examples of issues that you've encountered?